# Switch account in web app when using Google Sign-in

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-signin

I've implemented Google Sign-In in my web app and the users should have the option to switch accounts.
Switching accounts would be done basically by logging out, then logging in, but after having the option to select one of the accounts.
However, it seems that whenever the user wants to log in back, they are not prompted which account to select and instead, they are logged in with the one used initially.
So, how can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `signIn` with options to control this.

`signIn({ prompt: 'select_account' })` is what you want.

> **select_account**
>
> The authorization server prompts the user to select a Google account. This allows a user who has multiple accounts to select amongst the multiple accounts that they may have current sessions for.

See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthsigninoptions.